# AWS problem with authentication - cannot connect to ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Can anyone explain why I cannot connect to my ec2? I have tried to solve the problem by myself but without success.

Firstly, created the key :

```
aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name mykeys --region eu-central-1 --output text > mykeys.pem
```

Then created ec2 instance:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-06ec8443c2a35b0ba --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name mykeys --security-group-ids sg-xxx --subnet-id subnet-xxx
```

Every now and then I get permission deny when trying to connect to the ec2;

```
The authenticity of host 'ec2-18-185-248-81.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com (18.185.248.81)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:SbRamk5HTetJT6ysgqq3MLdsUU6Ehi/kYRWXtgwS3q4.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-18-185-248-82.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Load key "mykeys.pem": invalid format
ec2-user@ec2-18-185-248-81.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

It isn't also possible to connect via EC2 Instant Connect from within AWS

```
ec2-user@ec2-3-67-176-40.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Is it possible that the key was created wrongly?

```
Load key "mykeys.pem": invalid format
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking step by step to create pem.

In your cli, it seems `--query` is missed. [ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#having-ec2-create-your-key-pair)

Create pem:

```
aws ec2 create-key-pair \
    --key-name mykeys \
    --query "KeyMaterial" \
    --output text > mykeys.pem
```

Permission change:

```
chmod 400 mykeys.pem
```

(Create EC2 wit pem.)

Connect ssh:

```
ssh -i mykeys.pem ec2-user@<YourServerIP>
```

Comment: Thanks for help! I purposefully omited --querry flag condidering it not mandatory (and not finding much info about it in AWS docs). I will follow the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:

https://sjsadowski.com/invalid-format-ssh-key/

> While literally true, it is a pretty poorly written error message. What it actually means is that the key is a deprecated format, and
> what it does not tell you is that in the future the format will become
> completely unsupported.
>
> The solution here is to replace your rsa-sha1 keys with either ecdsa
> or ed25519 keys, distribute those keys, and then remove the old ones.
>
> The problem on AWS is that when you generate a key pair, it is still
> rsa-sha1 format, and while you can upload rsa-sha2 keys, ecdsa or
> ed25519 keys are not acceptable. There are questions about this going
> back to 2017 on the AWS forums, asking about other key formats.